# Ec2 RMI invocation - java.rmi.UnknownHostException: Unknown host: ip-xxx.xx.xx.xx

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, jboss, rmi, ejb-3.0

I have deployed a Hello EJB in jboss 5.1.0.GA and when I try to invoke the EJB from my java client I am getting java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-xxxxxxxxx.compute.internal

below is my provider URL.

private static final String PROVIDER_URL = "jnp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1099";

Note:

1. Adding the IP to etc/hosts is not working... connection refused is the error then
2. I am able to telnet  1099 from my laptop. My EC2 instance is open to the world for all traffic (This is how i configured my security group. I know its not safe -  just for testing)

Any help/suggestions?

Regards,

Shankar

Comment: 'Connection refused' is a lot better than 'unknown host'. The service isn't running on port 1099, or maybe at all.

Comment: It is running on port 1099. I can see that in jboss admin console as well as the server logs.

Comment: And listening at some IP address beyond 127.0.0.1?